# Will I use "the" in that instance or leave it with no article?

Tags: technical-writing, academic-writing, word-choice, writers-block

If I'm given a choice, to put "the" or leave the word with no article, what's the better answer?

- The world helps in boosting young confidence.
- The world helps in boosting the young confidence.

Thank you.

Comment: Depends on context. Give more details about 'young confidence.'

Answer (score 0):

Here goes.

It depends on *your* distinction and calculation of how many “young confidence” there is.

Check this out:

The opposite of the definite article is the *indefinite article*, either “a” or “an” depending on whether the word which follows begins with either a consonant or vowel, respectively. The simple difference between a definite article and indefinite articles is a matter of how many things you are referring to:

For example, the difference between “a dog” and “the dog”; in the use of “the dog” I know which dog I am referring to since there is a *definite* number of dog; in the use of “a dog” I do not know which dog I am referring to, for there is an *indefinite* number of dog.

With this in mind, “the young confidence” means that there is an absolute confidence, a *definite* confidence, and there is only *the* young confidence and therefore *no* other.

However, if we use “a young confidence”, we mean that there are *variations* of young confidence, that there may even be “young confidence” which is unidentified.

You as the Writer must have in mind whether there are variations of young confidence or whether there is only one absolute young confidence.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

I cannot explain the reason. But, intuitively, the second choice, ie 'The world helps in boosting the young confidence.'